# unqualified version of type in ANSI C

Tags: c

The Constraints portion of Section 6.3.2.2 of the ANSI C Standard includes the phrase:

Each argument shall have a type such that its value may be assigned to an object with the unqualified version of the type of its corresponding parameter.

---

Then, What the term 'unqualified version of type' means?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C99 draft contains the following language, about the use of the word "qualified":

> Any type so far mentioned is an unqualified type. Each unqualified type has several
>   qualified versions of its type, corresponding to the combinations of one, two, or all
>   three of the `const`, `volatile`, and `restrict` qualifiers.
>
> The qualified or unqualified versions of a type are distinct types that belong to the same type category and have the same representation and alignment requirements.

So your quote says that an argument having a `const int` must match a value of type `int`, and so on.

Comment: `const int *i; int j; i = &j;` now, did you mean `i` points to qualified version of `j`?

Answer (score 3):

Without bothering to check the specification, I would venture a guess that it has to do with e.g. `const` or `volatile` keywords.

For example, if you have an argument of type `const int`, you should be able to assign it to a variable of type `int` (without the `const` qualifier).

Comment: const `int *i; int j; i = &j;` now, did you mean ``i points to qualified version of `j`?

Comment: @silentboy No the other way, the pointer `*i` is const-qualified, while `j` is unqualified.